# How to store user data in cloud for free from my app?

Tags: android, cloud, storage

I am writing an Android application in which users will have personal data (and only personal data). I would like to have some way for them to store it in the cloud without me paying, for example, so that their data is stored in their Google Drive (though not necessarily accessible through Google Drive UI). Is there an easy solution for this?

I had a look at Firebase, but it seems that it has 'common' data storage, which would be associated with a developer's (that is mine) account.

Answer (score 2):

You can use FireBase. It's a great platform to host your app content 
https://firebase.google.com/

Answer (score -1):

you could create a database to store the data, but you'll require to keep a server running 24/7 if you don't want to pay for it. Also I don't see the drawback of associating the user data with your account as long as you don't rat out yourself.